# list of data saving in database using hibernate java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 3 entities named Stock,StockHistory and StockOpenClose. And there is common column stock_id in each entity. My problem is that, I have to save list of data into each.

```
   for (Stock stok : stockList) {
                    session.saveOrUpdate(stok);
                    session.flush();

                    for (StockOpenAndClose openStk : stockOpenCloseList) {
                        if (stockOpenCloseList != null) {
                            openStk.setStock_id(stok.getStock_id());
                            session.save(openStk);
                            session.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    for (StockHistory stkHis : stkHisList) {
                        stkHis.setStock_id(stok.getStock_id());
                        session.saveOrUpdate(stkHis);
                        session.flush();
                    }
}
```

I am saving like this and data are saving.And I know this is wrong. Because **stock_id** will be same according to the for each loop iteration. I want get the corresponding **stock_id** in both **StockHistory**, **StockOpenClose** entities. How can I do that??Can anyone correct me?

Comment: first of all u need to configure ur entity model in that you can use @PrimaryJoinColumn for you stock,stockHistory,stockOpenCloseTable so and than u need to store ur stock object

Comment: @LowCool I have already done JoinColumn and a ManyToOne relationship too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < stockList.size(); i++) {
  Stock stok = stockList.get(i);
  StockOpenAndClose openStk = stockOpenCloseList.get(i);
  StockHistory stkHis = stkHisList.get(i);
  session.saveOrUpdate(stok);
  session.flush();

  openStk.setStock_id(stok.getStock_id());
  session.save(openStk);

  stkHis.setStock_id(stok.getStock_id());
  session.saveOrUpdate(stkHis);
  session.flush();
}
```

but it will be better and simpler if you learn about "hibernate cascade" [here some example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

Comment: yea..this is working and currently I can solve my problems with this. And sure I will try "hibernate cascade". Thank you